# Jmeter sometimes shows "WARN c.h.c.r.e.LoggingCSSParseErrorHandler:" message while running the script

Tags: jmeter

Sometimes I am getting the following WARN message while executing my script:

Note: I have set "css.parser.ignore_all_css_errors=true" in jmeter.properties file and still getting the message intermittently:

2018-08-29 16:19:30,702 WARN c.h.c.r.e.LoggingCSSParseErrorHandler: Browser compliant mode skipped CSS from [5:227048] starting at token '100%' until [5:227058] to token ';' (based on com.helger.css.parser.ParseException: Encountered unexpected token: "+" "+"
    at line 5, column 227052.

Was expecting one of:

```
")"
<S>
```

)
2018-08-29 16:19:30,941 WARN c.h.c.r.e.LoggingCSSParseErrorHandler: Browser compliant mode skipped CSS from [5:188823] starting at token '100%' until [5:188833] to token ';' (based on com.helger.css.parser.ParseException: Encountered unexpected token: "+" "+"
    at line 5, column 188827.
..........

Please help me if you have a suggestion on how to fix this issue.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates the problem with the [CSS style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) on one of the pages of the application under test. Locate the problematic file and use [CSS Validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to identify problems and report them.

It might also be the case that the error appears under the load, i.e. CSS style referenced in the page is not downloaded fully resulting in parsing error, if this is the case - you found the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) which needs to be reported as well.

If you just want the error to disappear from JMeter logs you can [decrease JMeter log level verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the class by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Logger name="com.helger.css.reader.errorhandler.LoggingCSSParseErrorHandler" level="fatal" />
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change